# SQL Server from Express edition to Enterprise Edition licensing

Tags: sql-server

Good morning, soon we plan to migrate a SQL Server Express to a SQL Server Enterprise. This SQL is hosted on a virtual machine with 8 cores on 2 sockets.

A priori the SQL Express edition only uses one socket of the four cores.

I am reviewing the documentation and it is not clear to me if at the time of migrating the SQL I must buy licenses for all sockets / cores or I can only buy a license for one socket (4 cores).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/2/9/e29a9331-965d-4faa-bd2e-7c1db7cd8348/SQL_Server_2019_Licensing_guide.pdf

**How to license individual virtual machines using the Per Core licensing model**

Similar to the Per Core licensing model in physical OSEs, all virtual cores (v-cores) supporting virtual OSEs that are running instances of SQL Server 2019 software must be licensed accordingly. To license individual VMs using the Per Core model, customers must purchase a core license for each v-core (or virtual processor, virtual CPU, virtual thread) allocated to the VM, subject to a four-core license minimum per VM. For licensing purposes, a v-core maps to a hardware thread.